# Macro shortcut problem with texstudio

Tags: macros, texstudio, shortcut

I'm using TeXstudio 2.12.6 for mac. The shortcuts for macros can be customized in Preference, but these shortcuts seem to be bound to the positions of the macros in the list, rather than the names of the macros. So, for example, if there're two macros A,B at the beginning, with shortcuts a,b, and I add another macro C between A and B, then the shortcut b would be bound to C, rather than B. How can I prevent this automatic change of shortcuts when macros are added or removed?

Comment: This question appears to be about TeXstudio, rather than about something related to TeX, LaTeX, and friends. As such, the query might better be addressed to a TeXstudio-related forum than to this site.

Comment: This is a known issue (and has been for a few years now), and is currently in the feature request list: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/706/ It's not available as an option currently as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Troy Thanks for the link. 2014... There seems no hope for this problem to be fixed...

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Converting my comment into a community wiki answer, and kindly request to be informed to delete this answer in the future should the feature request be fulfilled by the TXS core developers.</sub>

This is a known issue since 2014, and is currently in the [feature request list](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/706).
The desired functionality is not available as an option currently as far as I can tell.